# UITextView (in UITableViewCell) scroll to current location

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextview

I'm trying to make a `UITextView` dynamically size itself, and scroll its location when new line gets inserted.

The `textView` is in a `UITableViewCell`. The cells height is set to `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`.

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
    if ([text isEqualToString:@"\n"])
    {
        NSRange cursor = NSMakeRange(range.location + 1, 0);

        NSMutableString *mutableT = [NSMutableString stringWithString:textView.text];
        [mutableT insertString:@"\n " atIndex:range.location];
        [textView setText:mutableT];

        [textView setSelectedRange:cursor];
        [textView sizeToFit];
        [textView layoutIfNeeded];

        [self.myTableView beginUpdates];
        [self.myTableView endUpdates];
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

It all works fine up until a new line gets inserted and the current `textViews` range (cursor) goes out of view. When that happens, the `tableView` gets scrolled to the top. But as soon as another `char` gets inserted, then it scrolls back to the correct position.

Question:

How can I get the `tableView` not to scroll all the way up?

Answer (score 0):

Insert this line between your `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` call.

```
[self.myTableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPathOfYourCell] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

Comment: t removes the text every time I enter a new line. My question is not about reloading tableViews, it's about dynamically sizing textViews